# Why Dockerfile doesn't run multiple commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want use Docker run my project(react+nodejs+mongodb), 
[image: this is my project directory]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../

COPY . .

CMD nohup sh -c 'npm start && node ./server/server.js'
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  chat:
    image: chat
    container_name: chat
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

run docker-compose up --build, the 3000 port is worked, but the 8080 port dies

[localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxGsW.png)

[localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PyHc.png)

Comment: did you run your app on port 8080, can you check server.js file ?

Comment: have you got any logs?  Also it's difficult to figure it out without the code, just the server.js file would do.  Why are you moving the node_modules folder

Comment: What do you mean by port 8080 dies? If your process does not listen on port 8080 then it is obvious that you won't get any connectivity from there. What is suppose to be on 8080? Your server? If yes then what is on port 3000 then?

Comment: 8080 port is my server, 3000 port is the react app port

Comment: which service listening on port 8080 ?

Comment: nodejs, i use nodejs connecting mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a container for the server and have it seperate from the "chat" container. Its best to have each container do one thing and one thing only (almost like the philosophy behind unix commands)

In any case here is some modifications that I would make to the compose file.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  chat:
    image: chat
    container_name: chat
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
#   You don't need to expose this port to the outside world. Because you linked the two containers the chat app
# will be able to connect to mongodb using hostname mongodb inside the container network.
#    ports:
#      - "27017:27017"
```

Btw what happens if you run:

```
$ docker-compose down
```

and then

```
$ docker-compose up

$ docker ps
```

can you see the ports exposed in docker ps output?

Answer (score 0):

your chat service depends on mongo so you also need to have this in your chat

```
depends_on:
  - mongo
```

This docker-compose file works for me. Note that i am saving the data from the database to a local directory. You should add this directory to gitignore.

```html
version: "3.2"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - "28017:27017"
    expose:
      - 28017 # you can connect to this mongodb with studio3t
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb-data:/data/db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - docker-network
  express:
    container_name: express
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        buildno: 1
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo # link this service to the database service
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: "npm start" # override the default command to use nodemon in dev
    networks:
      - docker-network
networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

You may also find that using node you have to wait for the mongodb container to be ready before you can connect to the database.